# Реализация sorted в python: может ли sorted() возвращать разные результаты при одних и тех же входных данных?

Tags: python, сортировка

Допустим у меня есть список

`a = [('a', 10), ('b', 9), ('c', 10), ('d', 9)]`.

Будет ли одно и то же в результате нескольких вызовов

`sorted(a,key=lambda n: n[1])`?

Ведь отсортировать такой список можно по-разному:

```
[('b', 9), ('d', 9), ('a', 10), ('c', 10)] или 
[('b', 9), ('d', 9), ('с', 10), ('a', 10)] или 
[('d', 9), ('b', 9), ('a', 10), ('c', 10)] и т.д.
```

Другими словами, является ли функция `sorted()` детерминированной?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sorted()` [стабильна](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1915376/4279) поэтому порядок одинаковых элементов из исходного списка гарантированно сохраняется.

В общем случая, результат, может быть разным от запуска к запуску, в зависимости от ключа:

```
>>> import random
>>> sorted([1,2,3], key=lambda _: random.randrange(10))
[2, 1, 3]
>>> sorted([1,2,3], key=lambda _: random.randrange(10))
[1, 3, 2]
```

И, конечно, в реализации могут быть [(теоретические) баги](https://bugs.python.org/issue23515).

См. также [About Python's built in sort() method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1517347/4279).